# How do you map a virtual drive letter to a local path on Windows?

Tags: windows

All in the title. I'm looking for how to reference a local, not network, path, as a virtual drive letter. An innocuous example:  `C:\Storage` as `G:`

Comment: Deleting from the lettered drive seems to have the annoying side effect of bypassing the recycle bin. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently researched this subject and these are my findings.

---

The [subst](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx) command performs this function well, and its effect ends with the user session:

```
subst [drive1: [drive2:]Path]
```

[vSubst](http://home.datacomm.ch/t.bigler/utils.html) by Thomas Bigler is a GUI for subst, it can also create a permanent association by running itself at startup (HKLM), just as *subst* could be configured to do.

For a permanent mapping this may not be preferable as anything loaded prior won't be able to reference the mapping, for instance entries added beforehand alongside it in HKLM -> [...] -> Run, Windows services, etc.

[psubst](http://code.google.com/p/psubst/) on Google Code is an excellent batch script with the interface of subst (which it uses internally) with an additional optional `/p` parameter for managing permanent mappings through the following key, which is loaded much earlier:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also map to your local drive as if it were a remote one with

```
net use G: \\localhost\c$\storage /persistent:yes
```

It does bind late in the login process though.

Comment: I don't think I knew that. Clever.